# syntax error near unexpected token `(' when building a docker image from dockerfile

Tags: powershell, docker

I am trying to run the below command over an alpine image in my docker file:

I have powershell installed and trying to get chocolatey through powershell commands.

```
RUN pwsh -c Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

and running into this error

> /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I also tried including the below and ran into the same issue.

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"] \
RUN shopt -s extglob
```

Comment: Enclose everything after `-c` in `'...'`, and use `"..."` around the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **'**

`RUN pwsh -c 'Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"))'`